# Windows 10 Start Menu Search Bar Not Showing Programs

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, cortana

I have been having a problem with my start menu in Windows 10!

When I search up a program like "Paint" or "Photoshop" it does not show up! However, built-in apps such as "Settings" and "Edge" show up!

I have tried rebuilding the search index earlier today, but it did not work, so, I am rebuilding the search index again and I am leaving it on overnight!

By the way, the items in my search index is over one million items when it is completed!

What should I do to fix my start menu search bar?

Comment: Windows 10 has had some strange start menu issues in the past, but seems to be much better in newer versions. Are you running an old version of Windows 10? I would recommend using anniversary edition.

Comment: I have a new version of Windows 10 that is the creator's update!

Comment: Had same issue about a month ago, sfc /scannow ended up throwing up a heap of errors as well.. have you recently done a reset/refresh or something similar?

Comment: No! I have not resetted or refreshed my computer! By the way, since you had the same problem as mine, did you fix it, and, if you did, how did you fix it?